# Android: Simple facebook onLoginListener cannot be resolved

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

Im using the simple facebook library, i have this code:

```
import com.sromku.simple.fb.listeners.OnLoginListener;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.Permission;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebook;
import com.sromku.simple.fb.SimpleFacebookConfiguration;



 public class MainActivity extends Activity {



private SimpleFacebook mSimpleFacebook;

private Button mButtonLogin;

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    mSimpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
} 

// login listener
OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new SimpleFacebook.OnLoginListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onFail(String reason)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking()
    {
        // show progress bar or something to the user while login is happening
        Log.i(TAG, "In progress");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogin()
    {
        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotAcceptingPermissions()
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "User didn't accept read permissions");
    }

};
```

I get one error in the OnLoginListener, it says the "SimpleFacebook.OnLoginListener cannot be resolved", i have imported the OnLoginListener so i dont understand why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you write `new SimpleFacebook.OnLoginListener()`? The class `SimpleFacebook` doesn't contain `OnLoginListener`.

You already imported `com.sromku.simple.fb.listeners.OnLoginListener` and that's why creating the listener should be following:

```
OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener()
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need implement this...

```
 OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLogin() {
        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
        Log.i("", "Logged in");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotAcceptingPermissions(Permission.Type type) {
        // user didn't accept READ or WRITE permission
        Log.w("", String.format("You didn't accept %s permissions", type.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(String reason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onThinking() {

    }
```